# Batch file to get current resolution on windows 10

Tags: batch-file

I try to read the current resolution, when the resoltuitoon is not 4k a flag is that to false, when it changes back to 4K a video process is killed and restarted.

but I get always the maximal resolution in the screen, on different windows machines.

```
@echo off

set resolution=false

:loop

Set "WMIC_Command=wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription^,CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution^ /format:Value"

Set "H=CurrentHorizontalResolution"
Set "V=CurrentVerticalResolution"
Call :GetResolution %H% HorizontalResolution
Call :GetResolution %V% VerticalResolution

echo(
echo Screen Resolution is : %HorizontalResolution% x %VerticalResolution% = %resolution%
timeout /t 2

if %HorizontalResolution% == 3840 (
  if %resolution% == false (
    echo "hoppla die Auflösung wurde geaendert"
    TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq SHH_Wandprojektion*"
      echo "Video task gekillt"
      timeout /t 2
      start "E:\_projekte\STADTHOEFE_HAMBURG\PROJEKTION_VIDEO\mpc-hc.exe" "E:\_projekte\STADTHOEFE_HAMBURG\PROJEKTION_VIDEO\SHH_Wandprojektion_200123b_1.mp4"
      echo "und wieder geoeffnet"
    set resolution=true
  )
) else (
  set resolution=false
)

timeout /t 3
goto loop


::****************************************************
:GetResolution 
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I IN (
  '%WMIC_Command% ^| find /I "%~1" 2^>^nul'
) DO FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ("%%I") DO SET "%2=%%A"
Exit /b
::****************************************************
```

a alternative way also prints only the max resolution of the screen:

```
for /f "tokens=4,5 delims=. " %%a in ('ver') do set "version=%%a%%b"

if version lss 62 (
    ::set "wmic_query=wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight, screenwidth /format:value"
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%@ in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth /format:value') do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%# in ("%%@") do set "x=%%#"
    )
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%@ in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenheight /format:value') do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%# in ("%%@") do set "y=%%#"
    )

) else (
    ::wmic path Win32_VideoController get VideoModeDescription,CurrentVerticalResolution,CurrentHorizontalResolution /format:value
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%@ in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution  /format:value') do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%# in ("%%@") do set "x=%%#"
    )
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%@ in ('wmic path Win32_VideoController get CurrentVerticalResolution /format:value') do (
        for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%# in ("%%@") do set "y=%%#"
    )

)

echo Resolution %x%x%y%
```

Comment: __"but I get always the maximal resolution in the screen"__ how is that? You are calling CurrentResolution specifically.

Comment: I can set the display to whatever, allways 4K!

Comment: I got actua rates, utilizing 'getwmiproperty.exe' on 10.0.18362.592

Comment: I switched to python, works great. I have 3 machines returning the max resolution when checking the current values.